# удаление слова из строки по букве и индексу в этом слове

Tags: python

У меня есть некая строка со словами одинакового размера, необходимо удалить слово по индексу, если там находится конкретная буква.
Вот пример кода:

```
 proverka_2 = input("Нажмите Enter чтобы продолжить! ", )
while proverka_2 != 'Да':
    words_1 = stro_ka.split(',  ')
    new_word_1 = []
    bukva_2 = input("Введите известную букву: ", )
    mesto = int(input('Введите место в котором его нет: ', ))
    for poisk_vernoj_1 in len(words_1):
        if bukva_2 == poisk_vernoj[mesto + 1]:
            new_word_1.append(poisk_vernoj)
            stro_ka = ' '.join(new_word)
    proverka_2 = input("Это всё? Да/Нет: ", )
print(stro_ka)
```

Comment: Приведите пример, не вполне ясно, что вам нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял, то твоя функция будет выглядеть так

```
s = "стрка буквы размр"
def wordDelete(s, indx, letter):
    s = s.split()
    if letter in s[indx]:
        s.pop(indx)
    return " ".join(s)

print(wordDelete(s, 1, "в"))
print(wordDelete(s, 0, "х"))
# Так сможешь запихнуть сюда input
#print(wordDelete(s,int(input("Индекс:")), input("Буква: ")))
```

> стрка размр

> стрка буквы размр

Текстовое сопровождение действиям добавить не сложно, если не разберёшься - пиши

P.S. Вообще можно и 1 строкой обойтись, вот только насколько это читабельно..

```
wordDelete = lambda s, indx, letter: " ".join([word for num, word in enumerate(s.split()) if num != indx or letter not in word])
```

Comment: спасибо ваше решение очень помогло

Answer (score 0):

В чем трудность возникает? Судя по условию, Вам надо удалить ориентируясь на:

- букву;
- индекс, а пишите о размерах слова.

Размеры слов то тут при чем?

Ниже код удаления по индексу или слову.

```python
ver_str = "Нажмите Enter чтобы продолжить! "
def word(
  my_string : str,
  one_word = None,
  id_word = None,
  ):
  if one_word == None and id_word != None\
   and type(id_word) == int\
   and id_word <= (len(my_string) - 1):

    list_of_string =  str(my_string).strip().split(" ")
    word_for_delete = list_of_string.pop(id_word)

    new_my_string = str(my_string).replace(word_for_delete, " ")
    return new_my_string


  if one_word != None and type(one_word) == str:

     new_my_string = str(my_string).replace(str(one_word), "") # первое попавшееся слово
    return new_my_string
```

Если необходима буква, то есть `str.find('word')` Покажет индексЫ первой попавшейся буквы.

Not: Переменная типа строки не редактируемая/не изменяемая. Каждое изменение это фактически за счет копии строки

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

из вашего вопроса не ясно что вы хотите, постарайтесь яснее изложить задачу и приведите пример исходных данных и желаемого результата.

этот код удаляет из строки слова если в них на заданной позиции находится заданный символ:

```
text = 'test1, test2, test3, test4'

c = input('char: ')
i = int(input('indx: '))  # индексация с 0
', '.join(filter(lambda x: i>=len(x) or x[i]!=c, text.split(', ')))

>>> out
'''
char: 3
indx: 4
'test1, test2, test4'
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь